# Creating Tables and Bar Plots in R as a Beginner

Tags: r, dataframe

I've begun using R recently so this might be simple to solve. I actually have two problems but I believe they`re connected.

I have a simple dataset (.csv file with 3 columns and 7 rows) and I'm trying to create a table out of it and plot a bar graph with the values of the two numerical columns.

```
Grupo de idade;Freq. Relativa Homens;Freq. Relativa Mulheres
16 a 19;0,411;0,415
20 a 24;0,787;0,701
25 a 34;0,922;0,745
35 a 44;0,923;0,755
45 a 54;0,882;0,760
55 a 64;0,696;0,583
65 ou mais;0,205;0,126

df = read.csv(filename, header = TRUE, sep = ";")
tab = table(df)
sd = cbind(df$Freq.Homens, df$Freq.Mulheres)
barplot(sd, beside = TRUE)
```

So first my table ends up looking like this, with the values as headers:

```
Freq..Relativa.Homens
Grupo.de.idade 0,205 0,411 0,696 0,787 0,882 0,922 0,923
    16 a 19        0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    20 a 24        0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    25 a 34        0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    35 a 44        0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    45 a 54        0     0     0     0     1     0     0
    55 a 64        0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    65 ou mais     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

And my graph is plotted with integers values like 2, 4, and 6. I noticed that happened because of the `cbind` function, but without it, I can`t plot anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help further, can you describe a bit more of what you need? In terms of a table, what are the rows and columns? For example, would rows be age groups, and would there be 2 columns: one for men and one for women? (Also, to confirm - relative frequencies should not add up to 100% between men/women?) For plot, would age groups by the horizontal axis, and relative frequency be vertical axis? With bars for men and women separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: R thinks anglo-american (; , i.e. the decimal mark is a ".".

The decimal mark in your data is a ",". You have to tell this to R,  by adding the  argument `dec = ","``, i.e.

```
df = read.csv(filename, header = TRUE, sep = ";". dec = ",")
```

Otherwise R interprets the numbers as characters or strings

`table` makes a contigency table of two variables. This however makes only sense for categorical variables, e.g. number of observations by age and sex.

You have only one categorical variable (Grupo.de.idade) and two continuous variables

R does the best to make sense of this, and simply interprets the values of the continuous variables as categories, which however makes no sense, e.g there is 1 observation in your data set with "Grupo de idade" = "16 a 19" and a value of "0,411" for "Freq. Relativa Homens". That's what `table` is telling you.

Moreover your data is already in table format so if you want to have a look at your data  simply type `df` to the console

```
df
#>   Grupo.de.idade Freq..Relativa.Homens Freq..Relativa.Mulheres
#> 1        16 a 19                 0.411                   0.415
#> 2        20 a 24                 0.787                   0.701
#> 3        25 a 34                 0.922                   0.745
#> 4        35 a 44                 0.923                   0.755
#> 5        45 a 54                 0.882                   0.760
#> 6        55 a 64                 0.696                   0.583
#> 7     65 ou mais                 0.205                   0.126
```

The easiest way to meke a simple barplot is like this:

```
barplot(Freq..Relativa.Homens ~ Grupo.de.idade, data = df)
```

On the left of the "~" put the variable to plot, on the right the grouping variable. Furthermore you have to tell R  the name of the dataset.

[image]

However, instead of a trial-and-error-approach to R I recommend to work through the introductory chapters of one of the free tutorials or textbooks one can find on the internet, like [The Pirate's guide to R](https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/)

<sup>Created on 2020-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: My pleasure. If you want do me a favor: Mark the question as answered. Besides giving me some credit it shows others with a similar problem that the solution worked and removes the question from the queue of questions still waiting for an answer.